# Expandable Listview not filling Dialog

Tags: android, expandablelistview, android-alertdialog

I'm using an expandable list view in an alert dialog (custom).

I am setting the view for the list like this:

```
   alertDialogBuilder.setView(myView);
```

However i notice that the list doesn't stretch to occupy the whole view and i have to scroll within that list as shown in the image below:

[image]

Here's my xml code as well:

```
<ExpandableListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/listview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:groupIndicator="@null"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
```

Has anyone ever had this problem before or know how to tackle it, i could set the height of the expandable listview but i wan't to refrain from that.

Comment: I don't understand your picture... but why the list should stretch if you are setting "wrap content" as height?

Comment: @rupps it should wrap the content of all the items, 3 in this case. But its not doing that, its only showing 2 and then i have to scroll to see the ones below.

Comment: "wrap content" does not mean wrap parent height to all the items, it means that the list height's gonna be the sum of the heights of each of its items, without any relation to the parent height: exactly what you are getting. What you need to do is set the height to "match parent" and set a dialog height at construction time big enough to hold your desired number of items.